# Creating a spss file in multiple languages

Tags: c#, asp.net, spss

SPSS  dll i have does  not support encoding. It reads French and German OK but any double byte language string, e.g. Chinese, Japanese, or Russian, reads back as "???"
// At binary level, the buffer actually contains "3f" for each "?". This may be the result of a failed unicode conversion.

When we write into .sav file, the interface only allows us to set interface encoding (not file level encoding, or code page). I suspect maybe the dll does not support double byte languages.

I have created SPSSDocument for write data  but  cannot find any encoding while creating file.

**Can anyone help me in this issue?**